# Refined jsonPath mapping between AWS Steps

Tags: aws-step-functions

Is there a way in AWS Step to map output from one state to the input of the next state beyond what's offerend with `InputPath`, `OutputPath`,`ResultPath`?

e.g. Example output from the first state:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "body": {
          "access_token":"example_token"
     }
}
```

The next State expects input of the form:

```
{
    "method": "foo",
    "payload": {
         "access_token":<my_access_token>,
         "other_key":"other_value"
    },
    "other_params":["a","b","c"]
}
```

It's not clear how to arbitrarily map the output of 1 state to the input of another.  The only solution appears to be rewriting the Lambdas.

Essentially I need something like:

```
"Remap": {
  "Type": "Pass",     
  "Result": {
    "method":"foo",
    "payload":{
        "access_token":"$.body.access_token",
        "other_key":"other_value"
    },
    "other_params":["a","b","c"]
  },
  "Next": "NextStage"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good generic way currently to manipulate the JSON from within the states language. As you say, it would be useful if the "Result" value of a Pass could be more expressive.

You could make an intermediary step lambda that generates the JSON you need. It's frustrating that if you made something generic like a "set-json-path" activity, calling it is unwieldy as you'd need an extra Pass step to set its parameters and they'd have to be added to the rest of the input. What the states language seems to need is a way to do a "sub-machine" with its own input/output.

You can almost get this functionality using Parallel but unfortunately the results are always in an array. This *almost* works but it puts access_token in an array instead of just a string:

```
{
   "StartAt": "Setup",

   "States": {

     "Setup": {
       "Type": "Pass",
       "Result": {
         "method":"foo",
         "payload":{
           "other_key":"other_value"
         },
         "other_params":["a","b","c"]
       },
       "Next": "Step1"
     },

     "Step1": {
       "Type": "Parallel",
       "Branches": [
         {
           "StartAt": "GetToken",
           "States": {
             "GetToken": {
               "Type": "Pass",
               "Result": {
                 "status": "1",
                 "body": {
                   "access_token":"example_token"
                 }
               },
               "OutputPath": "$.body.access_token",
               "End": true
             }
           }
         }
       ],
       "ResultPath": "$.payload.access_token",
       "Next": "Step2"
     },

     "Step2": {
       "Type": "Task",
       "Resource": "arn:....foo",
       "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
{
  "output": {
    "method": "foo",
    "payload": {
      "other_key": "other_value",
      "access_token": [
        "example_token"
      ]
    },
    "other_params": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
}
```

In your case, I think the easiest thing is to modify your first lambda task to just return the access token string which you can set using `ResultPath": "$.payload.access_token"`. Unfortunately there is tight coupling between the state machine and the input and output of each state (as well as the order in the array of Parallel states which irritates me to no end.)